# Solar biplane possibilty?

Tags: aerodynamics

The solar impulse has a massive wing span, greater than a jumbo jets. Would it not be possible to have a biplane design to shorten the wingspan(making it more practical and maneuverable)and have the wings offset so that they both capture the sun?

Comment: But wingspan is *good*. They *need* great wingspan.

Comment: Not very practical though for future transport. The drag produced from a biplane design would not be a big factor due to the slow speed of a solar plane.

Comment: The drag produced from a biplane design would be a huge factor, because it is the short span that causes the drag, _especially_ at low speed.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to increase wing chord? This way you only have one boundary layer (= less drag) and a much thicker wing. Makes you wonder why the designers of the Solar Impulse didn't choose to do so, doesn't it?